# Me sale el error: IndentationError: expected an indented block (PYTHON)

Tags: python

```
#bot

from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
PATH = '/users/nombre/documents/python/chromedriver'

class bot(videoName, watchtime):
    def __init__(self):
       self.browser = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
    
    def __home(self):
       self.browser.get("https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCqEUmSIH4fjjtwqGz4zLk_g?view_as=subscriber")
       sleep(2)

    def __videoPageID(self, elementNumber):
       self.ids = self.browser.find_element_by_id('thumbnail')
       return self.ids[elementNumber]
       

    def watchVideo(self, videoNumber, watchTime):
           self.videoNumber = videoNumber
           self.watchTime = watchTime
           if self.videoTitle in keys(videosXPath):
           self.__home(self)
           thumbnailElm = self.__videoID(self.videoNumber)
           thumbnailElm.click()
           sleep(self.watchTime)
           if self.videoTitle in videosXPath.keys():
               thumbnailElem = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath(videosXPath[videoTitle])
               thumbnailElem.click()
               sleep(watchTime)

              
           
myBot = Bot()
for i in range(18)
    myBot.watchVideo('i, 2')
```

Comment: Por favor lee la sección sobre [cómo elaborar una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y posteriormente edita tu pregunta para agregar más detalles sobre lo que intentas hacer ya que la pregunta no proporciona información necesaria para que alguien pueda ayudarte.

Answer (score 1):

El error  `IndentationError...` te está diciendo que tienes problemas con la indentación. Recuerda que [Python](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html) toma mucho en cuenta los espacios para definir en dónde empieza y dónde termina un bloque de código por lo que si no cuentas con los espacios adecuados obtendrás errores del tipo *IndentationError*. Esta indentacion comunmente es de [4 espacios por nivel](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation).

```py
# bot

from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
PATH = '/users/nombre/documents/python/chromedriver'


class bot(videoName, watchtime):
    def __init__(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

    def __home(self):
        self.browser.get("https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCqEUmSIH4fjjtwqGz4zLk_g?view_as=subscriber")
        sleep(2)

    def __videoPageID(self, elementNumber):
        self.ids = self.browser.find_element_by_id('thumbnail')
        return self.ids[elementNumber]

    def watchVideo(self, videoNumber, watchTime):
        self.videoNumber = videoNumber
        self.watchTime = watchTime
        if self.videoTitle in keys(videosXPath):
            self.__home(self)
            thumbnailElm = self.__videoID(self.videoNumber)
            thumbnailElm.click()
            sleep(self.watchTime)
            if self.videoTitle in videosXPath.keys():
                thumbnailElem = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath(videosXPath[videoTitle])
                thumbnailElem.click()
                sleep(watchTime)


myBot = Bot()
for i in range(18)
myBot.watchVideo('i, 2')
```